# Validate JSON-LD against Schema.org

Tags: c#, validation, json.net, schema.org, json-ld

I am processing Schema.org JSON-LD objects from a website. I need to know they validate against their Schema.org schema before using them. How?

As far as I understand Schema.org schemas are not JSON schemas, so a JSON schema validator like the one from json.net won't validate against those.
Just how is everybody else doing this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a Structured Data Testing Tool that validates schema.org written ion json-ld and microdata.

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

It also provides information about validity with regard to structured data based rich features the Google supports.