# Validating an JSON-LD JSON object against RDF

Tags: javascript, json, schema, rdfs

I have a JSON object that *should* be JSON-LD. I would like to programatically validate that is the case. The JSON-LD Spec has a `@context` and a `@type` that point a description document. In my particular use case, it is the very common schema.org. Supposedly these documents more describe what the data is, not what it looks like, but those two seem to be heavily related, especially with Schema.org even referencing types in their schema. It would be great to ensure properties and value types are validated.

I basically would like a self-hosted/Javascript version of: https://validator.schema.org/

Is there a Javascript implementation of this sort of validation?

[Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224386/validate-json-ld-against-schema-org]

Answer (score 0):

This [Blog post from Schema.org](http://blog.schema.org/2021/05/announcing-schema-markup-validator.html) (and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/2790) have some links to some tools:

- https://github.com/semantifyit/sdo-check/
- https://github.com/google/schemarama/

These seem to be relatively abandoned but might be a good starting place.